# GatsbyJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageFluid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I am working on a Gatsby website, and I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageFluid' of undefined"

The code I have is this in my Project.js file

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import Image from "gatsby-image"
import { FaGithubSquare, FaShareSquare } from "react-icons/fa"
const Project = ({description, title, github, stack, url, image, index}) => {
  return (
    <article className="project">
      <Image fluid={image.childImageFluid.fluid} className="project-img" />
    </article>
  ) 
}

Project.propTypes = {}

export default Project
```

and I have the graphql set up in the index.js file where it will be displayed, and everything is working as it should in graphql...

```
export const query = graphql`
         {
           allStrapiProjects(filter: { featured: { eq: true } }) {
             nodes {
               github
               id
               description
               title
               url
               image {
                 childImageSharp {
                   fluid {
                     ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
                   }
                 }
               }
               stack {
                 id
                 title
               }
             }
           }
         }
       `
```

everything up to the what I am working on in the Project.js file is in my github - https://github.com/matthewbert86/gatsby-site but all of that code is in the first code section above.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a page query in GraphQL, your gathered data is stored inside a `data` object (as a `props`). You need to iterate through it until you get your fluid image. It should be in: `props.data.allStrapiProjects.nodes.image.childImageFluid.fluid`. Since you are destructuring everything in your `<Project>` component:

```
const Project = ({ data }) => {
let { description, title, github, stack, url, image } = data.allStrapiProjects.nodes; // your data is here

return (
    <article className="project">
      <Img fluid={data.allStrapiProjects.nodes.image.childImageFluid.fluid} className="project-img" />
    </article>
  ) 
}
```

After destructuring, you can refactor it to:

```
  <Img fluid={image.childImageFluid.fluid} className="project-img" />
```

Another point, I guess that the `gatsby-image` import should be `Img`, not `Image`.